Class properties remains empty despite initialization default values and let properties used
I use property let and rightafter use property get and the value is empty though there was a default value on class initialization anyway. I can't understand why it is empty.
Built in Debug.Prints return "0 0 6"
On the commented one debug.print I have syntax error I have no idea why by the way.
main sub
Option Explicit
Public oClass1 As Class1

Sub main()

Set oClass1 = New Class1

Call oClass1.CreateSubClass

'Debug.Print oClass1.oClass2.sum2(oClass2.p_paramX1, oClass2.p_paramX2)

End Sub

Class1
Option Explicit
Public oClass2 As Class2

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub

Sub CreateSubClass()

Set oClass2 = New Class2

oClass2.p_paramX1 = 5
oClass2.p_paramX2 = 5

Debug.Print oClass2.p_paramX1 'return 0

Debug.Print oClass2.sum2(oClass2.p_paramX1, oClass2.p_paramX2) 'return 0
Debug.Print oClass2.sum2(3, 3) 'return 6

End Sub


Class2
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

Dim paramX1 As Integer
Dim paramX2 As Integer

paramX1 = 1
paramX2 = 2

End Sub
Public Function sum2(X1, X2)
     sum2 = X1 + X2
End Function

Public Property Get p_paramX1() As Integer
    p_paramX1 = paramX1
End Property

Public Property Let p_paramX1(value As Integer)
    paramX1 = value
End Property

Public Property Get p_paramX2() As Integer
    p_paramX2 = paramX2
End Property

Public Property Let p_paramX2(value As Integer)
    paramX2 = value
End Property



In Class2 you have Dim paramX1 As Integer
Dim paramX2 As Integer inside of Class_Initialize: these are not globals, and go out of scope right after you set their values.  Option Explicit would warn you about the issue (though the previous two listings have that?)

Moved declaration to Option Explicit from Initialization and it worked. According to Tim Wiliams comment.
Option Explicit
Private paramX1 As Integer
Private paramX2 As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

paramX1 = 1
paramX2 = 2


End Sub
Public Function sum2(X1, X2)

sum2 = X1 + X2

End Function

Public Property Get p_paramX1() As Integer
    p_paramX1 = paramX1
End Property

Public Property Let p_paramX1(value As Integer)
    paramX1 = value
End Property

Public Property Get p_paramX2() As Integer
    p_paramX2 = paramX2
End Property

Public Property Let p_paramX2(value As Integer)
    paramX2 = value
End Property

As for mentioned syntax error, correct call shall include full class chain.
    Debug.Print oClass1.oClass2.sum2(oClass1.oClass2.p_paramX1, oClass1.oClass2.p_paramX2)

